# Bluemix app push Invalid zip archive error

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an error when pushing my local changes to ibm cloud using the command "bluemix app push". Since I updated the version of bluemix cli to 0.7.0

Here's the error trace:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "error": "Use of entity>error is deprecated in favor of entity>error_details.",
    "error_details": {
      "code": 160001,
      "description": "The app upload is invalid: Invalid zip archive.",
      "error_code": "CF-AppBitsUploadInvalid"
    },
    "guid": "d02b3d10-5e25-4a4c-a9ae-03c7e37cb084",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "created_at": "2018-06-05T03:31:29Z",
    "guid": "d02b3d10-5e25-4a4c-a9ae-03c7e37cb084",
    "url": "/v2/jobs/d02b3d10-5e25-4a4c-a9ae-03c7e37cb084"
  }
}
```

Comment: I also got this issue but on a peculiar project:

- It has worked for a plain node.js server but it fails on a server serving a Vue.js front
- I checked some cloudfoundry's git issues and it looks like the project is too heavy to be deployed in 1 part (because Diego's agent .ZIPs your project directory)

So I'm working on using CDN to lighten the front. I'll give you more info :)